# DAX Count new and lost Customers per Day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple table that shows me per day our active customers. The structure is like:

```
Date    Customer
01.01.2021  AA
01.01.2021  BB
01.01.2021  CC
02.01.2021  AA
02.01.2021  BB
02.01.2021  CC
03.01.2021  AA
03.01.2021  BB
03.01.2021  CC
03.01.2021  DD
```

Now I would like to have a line chart that shows the number of new and lost customers per day.
How would you do that by using DAX?

Answer (score 0):

With the given structure, if you want to count `gain\loss` for a given date exactly relative to the `previous day`, you need to create the `X Axis` first, e.g. which are all the dates. I have solved it with a calendar Table

```
Table
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'fact',
        "lastDayofMonth",
            CALCULATE (
                MAXX (
                    FILTER ( 'calendar', 'calendar'[Calendar_Date] = MAX ( 'fact'[Date] ) ),
                    'calendar'[Last_Day_in_Month]
                )
            )
    )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATEALL (
        _1,
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'calendar'[Calendar_Date], [Date], [lastDayofMonth] )
    )
VAR _3 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "prev",
            MAXX (
                FILTER (
                    _2,
                    EARLIER ( [Cust] ) = [Cust]
                        && EARLIER ( [Calendar_Date] ) > [Calendar_Date]
                ),
                [Cust]
            )
    )
VAR _4 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _3,
            "gain",
                SWITCH ( TRUE (), [prev] = BLANK () && [Cust] <> BLANK (), 1, 0 )
        ),
        "loss",
            SWITCH ( TRUE (), [prev] <> BLANK () && [Cust] = BLANK (), 1, 0 )
    )
RETURN
    _4
```

Then you can create a measure to show the count of gain\loss each day

```
_gain:=
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE ( SUMX ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[gain] = 1 ), 'Table'[gain] ) )
VAR _2 =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _1 ) = TRUE (), 0, _1 )
RETURN
    _2
    

_loss:=
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[loss] ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[loss] ), 'Table'[loss] = 1 )
    )
VAR _2 =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _1 ) = TRUE (), 0, _1 )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]

It is dependent upon a calendar table with minimum structure like following

| Calendar_Date | Calendar_Year | Calendar_Month | Calendar_Day | First_Day_in_Month | Last_Day_in_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1/31/2021 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do some transformation in **Power Query Editor** and create a new table from your source table. The output will be as below-

[image]

From the above table, you can easily create your desired line chart. If I guess your table name "**your_source_table_name**", just use this below **Advance Editor** code for creating the **new table**. Remember, you have to change the table name in below code with your **source table name**.

```
let
    Source = #"your_source_table_name",
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Date", "Customer"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Date", type date}, {"Customer", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Custom", each Date.AddDays([Date] ,1)),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Date"}, #"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"Count"}, {"Added Custom.Count"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Added Custom.Count", "previous_day_count"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"previous_day_count"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "loss", each if [Count] < [previous_day_count] then [previous_day_count] - [Count] else 0),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "gain", each if [Count] > [previous_day_count] then [Count] - [previous_day_count] else 0)
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```